# Find the index of rows which has a special condition in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `(n,2)` array. I want to choose the index of array which their value is equal to the maximum of their rows. For example, in the below array, the maximum of column 0 is 7, and the maximum of column 1 is 10. So, I only want to get the rows which their values are (7,10). Here is an example:

```
 a = np.array([[1,2], [1,6], [7,10], [7, 10], [0,1], [1,9], [0,5]])
```

The desired output is:

```
output = np.array([2,3])
```

Thank you for your help.

I've tried to used the `np.select`, however it seems that have an arguments which need condition choice and etx, then it seems that its not effective. Also, I could not get the true value with that.

Comment: And in the case that the maximums in each column doesn't sit in the same rows, what outcome would you want?

Comment: I only want the index of the rows. The desire output is index 2 and index 3, which I show that in an array.

Comment: @saleh first occurrence of `10` is index 2 too, not 3?

Comment: @ali_sh Yes. at index 2, we have [7,10]! and iat index 3, we have also [7,10]. So, the output is index 2 and index3, or [2,3].

Comment: @saleh what it will show if we have `[3, 10], [7,10], [7, 10], [7, 11]`?

Comment: We only consider the rows which the first value is equal to the maximum of first column and same for the second value. So, here the answer is we only have only [7,11] with index 3 (or -1).

Answer (score 0):

In the first step we can find maximum values columnar using `np.amax` and then find rows where both columns satisfy the condition:

```
cols_max = np.amax(a, axis=0)
result = np.argwhere((a == cols_max).all(axis=1))  # add ".squeeze()" to reduce dimensions
```